# Как можно сохранять изображения в ImageField через библиотеку requests?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

как можно сохранять изображения в ImageField в Django ORM через код. Допустим, я загружаю изображения с другого сайта и мне надо их сохранять в свою модель, как это можно сделать, используя библиотеку requests?

Answer (score 1):

```
 В models.py

  class Img(models.Model)
  img_page = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/page/',
                                         verbose_name='фото страницы', 
                                         blank=True)
```

Если я правильно понял вопрос. Создаете в проекте папку images/page и ее указываете в поле модели. И при добавлении картинки через панель админа она будет лежать в этой папке.

Answer (score 0):

У нас есть модель:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

И есть ссылка на картинку:

```
photo_link = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/devmanorg/where-to-go-places/master/media/35cbdddf2799337d8b571d141edec616.JPG'
```

Код может выглядеть так:

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.db import models

from places.models import Photo 


response = requests.get(photo_link)
response.raise_for_status() # Проверяем ответ сервера

filename = 'Example' # Придумываем имя картинки

new_photo = Photo() # Создаем экземпляр фото 
new_photo.image.save(filename, ContentFile(response.content), save=True) # Записываем в него картинку по ссылке и сохр.
```

Полезные ссылки по теме:
https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/files/file/#additional-methods-on-files-attached-to-objects
https://devman.org/encyclopedia/modules/requests/